# Remove unmatched closing tag from html

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have some html stored in a string. The html is invalid and contains an unmatched closing `</span>` inside a `<td>` i.e.

```
<table>
  <tr><td>
    <p>First section of text.</p>
    <p>Second section of text.</span></p>
    <table>
      <tr><td>
        <p>Third section of text.</p>
      </td></tr>
    </table>
  </td></tr>
</table>

<p>Fourth section of text.</p>
```

I want to use BeautifulSoup to modify the html when I load this html into BS and extract as a string using:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print( str( soup.prettify() ) )
```

BS has modified the structure dramatically.

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <p>
    First section of text.
   </p>
   <p>
    Second section of text.
   </p>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <p>
    Third section of text.
   </p>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<p>
 Fourth section of text.
</p>
```

Without the unmatched `</span>` BS output is as I would expect

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <p>
    First section of text.
   </p>
   <p>
    Second section of text.
   </p>
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <p>
       Third section of text.
      </p>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<p>
 Fourth section of text.
</p>
```

What I would like to do is remove the unmatched  from the html. How can I do this without writing my own parser looking for unmatched tags? I was hoping that I could use BS to clean up the code, but it doesn't work.

Comment: When BS gets a close element, it closes until it find the matching open element.  Since there isn't one, it closes all the way up.  Seems like it is working correctly to me.   I don't see how you expect to be able to "fix" broken HTML in any general way.  Are mismatched span elements the only errors you expect?

Comment: I understand that it closes until it finds a matching element - although it would be more helpful if it only did that if there was a matching element. I know the html is badly formed, but I have no control over the input html, so looking for a way to cope with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could split it with `<span>` and then join.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data='''
<table>
  <tr><td>
    <p>First section of text.</p>
    <p>Second section of text.</span></p>
    <table>
      <tr><td>
        <p>Third section of text.</p>
      </td></tr>
    </table>
  </td></tr>
</table>

<p>Fourth section of text.</p>
'''


soup=BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
data="".join(item.strip() for item in data.split("</span>"))
print(data)
```

Here is the printed output.

```
<table>
  <tr><td>
    <p>First section of text.</p>
    <p>Second section of text.</p>
    <table>
      <tr><td>
        <p>Third section of text.</p>
      </td></tr>
    </table>
  </td></tr>
</table>

<p>Fourth section of text.</p>
```

Use decompose if `<span>...</span>` tag present in your html and want to remove it from html.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data='''
<table>
  <tr><td>
    <p>First section of text.</p>
    <p>Second section of text.<span>xxxxx</span></p>
    <table>
      <tr><td>
        <p>Third section of text.</p>
      </td></tr>
    </table>
  </td></tr>
</table>

<p>Fourth section of text.</p>
'''


soup=BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

soup.span.decompose()
print(soup)
```

Comment: That wouldn't work if there is a valid ```<span> </span>``` in the html. It would remove the closing tag incorrectly in that case

Comment: if <span>..</span> tag in html present and you want to get rid off  you can decompose it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a possible solution. Use html.parser to detect orphaned endtags and then remove them from the html before loading into BeautifulSoup.

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.taghash={}
        self.fixups = []

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if not tag in self.taghash:
            self.taghash[tag]=1
        self.taghash[tag] = self.taghash[tag] + 1

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if not tag in self.taghash:
            self.taghash[tag]=0
        self.taghash[tag] = self.taghash[tag] - 1
        if self.taghash[tag] < 0:
            print( "No unclosed starttag.", tag, self.getpos())
            self.fixups.append( (tag,self.getpos()))
```

```
    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    parser.feed(html)
    data = html.splitlines()
    parser.fixups.reverse()
    for fixup in parser.fixups:
        line = fixup[1][0]-1
        offset = fixup[1][1]
        m = re.search( "</\s*%s.?>"%fixup[0],data[line][offset:])
        data[line] = data[line][:offset]+data[line][offset+m.end():]
    html = "".join(data)
```